# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't get Updated to Update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm running this version of Visual Studio.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Version 12.0.20930.1 REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

Installed Version: Ultimate

Architecture and Modeling Tools   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft Architecture and Modeling Tools

UML® and Unified Modeling Language™ are trademarks or registered trademarks of the Object Management Group, Inc. in the United States and other countries.

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013

Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker   06181-004-0449004-02399
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   06181-004-0449004-02399
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU

ASP.NET and Web Tools   2013.1.41009
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Support for creating and opening ASP.NET web projects
Browser Link: A communication channel between Visual Studio and browsers
Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
Server Explorer extensions for Windows Azure Web Sites
Web publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting providers, on-premises servers, or Windows Azure

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.20927.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.0.10927.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

AutoHistory   1.0
Information about my package

BuildVision   1.0
Extension for visualization of building process

Common Azure Tools   1.0
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Windows Azure Tools.

JetBrains ReSharper 8.0.2   Full Edition build 8.0.2000.2660 on 2013-09-27T11:18:12
JetBrains ReSharper 8.0.2 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2014 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone   
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone
Build 

NuBuild.VS.Package   1.0
A NuGet project system for Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   2.8.50126.477
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.30919.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.0
Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools

Windows Azure Remote Debugging   1.0
Windows Azure Remote Debugging Community Technology Preview

Windows Azure Tools   2.2
Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.2.11003.1601

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.
```

When I go to the "Extension and Updates", it tells me I could update to Visual Studio 2013 update 1

[image]

Clicking in "Update", I get redirected to this page, where I could download and run VS2013.1.exe

Then I get this screen. Note there's no option to install, just repair or uninstall.

[image]

I already tried to repair, uninstall, install again (everything goes right) and it seems Visual Studio is never updated.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try searching the MS support site at all?

Comment: Yeap, thanks for asking.